# Python: when calling list.sort(), get ValueError about ambiguities?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, numpy

I need to sort eigenvalue-eigenvector pairs by descending order of eigenvalue magnitudes, and I sometimes (~1/3 of time) get the following error when calling the .sort() function:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

The bit of code that generates the error is this, on the eigenPairs.sort() call:

```
eigenPairs = []  # list of tuples of (eigenVal, eigenVect)
for i in range(len(eigenVals)):
    eigenPairs.append((eigenVals[i], eigenVects[:, i]))

eigenPairs.sort()  
eigenPairs.reverse()
```

The eigenVals and eigenVects variables are basically the results of an SVD on a matrix implemented in a custom method - the math behind that part checks out. The weird part is that when the code works, it works - I get the expected results.

Comment: Doesn't `eigenVects[:, i]` raise an error? E.g. `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`? If you want the values from 0 to i, use `eigenVects[:i]`

Comment: this `for i in range(len(eigenVals)):` looks very unpythonic.
Take a look at enumerate https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: Can you provide how `eigenVals` and `EigenVects` look like when it fails?

Comment: @jDo: That's a standard method for slicing multidimensional matrices in `numpy`; indexing with a `tuple` like that is perfectly legal if the type understands it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Cool cool. Just thought it was a regular list and missed the numpy tag.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of questions about this `ValueError`.  It's the result using `numpy` boolean array in a Python context that expects a scalar boolean.  Most commonly it's a `if x:..` statement.  Here I suspect it is the result of performing a list sort on a list containing arrays.

Either change it into a list of lists or tuples, define a functioning comparison function or key, or switch to array sort.

For example try to sort on just the 1st element of the tuple, which is a scalar.

What's the size of the 2nd element, the eigenvectors?  Any difference between the cases when it runs v. when it fails?

I bet you can accumulate the eigenvalues in an array and sort that.  Or `argsort` it.

---

```
  sorted(L, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
```

will restrict the sort to the first item of the tuples

https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#Key_Functions

https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#Operator_Module_Functions

I experimented with tuples that contain None in the 2nd slot.  Sort ignored that when the order of the 1st term was clear, but produced errors when it had use the 2nd term to resolve ties.

I'm guessing your sort was fine when eigenvalues were unique, but failed when there were duplicates and it tried to order the arrays.

Comment: the eigenvectors are all length-1800, and I thought python sorted lists by the first element of tuples by default?

Comment: I found a SO answer on sorting lists of lists that uses `itemgetter`.